# Replace a top document from an iframe without changing the current URL

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to replace the entire content of the top document from an iframe (same origin). Following JavaScript executed by the iframe does the job:

```
var doc = window.top.document.open("text/html", "replace");
doc.write('hello');
doc.close();
```

However, in Firefox, the operation changes the URL of the current document to the URL of the iframe. In Chrome the URL is not changed. Is it possible to replace the document from the iframe but keep its original URL in a way that works in all reasonable browsers? (I tried removing "replace" parameter, but it did not help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have to replace the complete content (including the head section etc.) you could try:

```
var html = 'YOUR HTML' /* your html string*/,
    url = "javascript:(function(){var c = '" +html +
           "';document.open();document.write(c);document.close();})();";
// replacing the original location with the dynamically generated one 
window.top.location.replace(url);
```

In this case the url would be the same as before. If you don't need to change the complete file, just the contents, you could use:

```
window.top.document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'YOUR HTML';
```

This will leave the head of top document unchanged, but would replace all contents without changing the url.

Comment: I need to replace the whole document, not just body. The first method indeed does the job in both Firefox and Chrome. Do you know if it is a common practice to put JavaScript directly in the url, or something to be used as a last resort? I wonder if it can cause some unexpected problems.

Comment: @JanWrobel I would see it as the last resort.

Comment: OK, I think, I'll change my approach and redirect to a different URL instead of replacing the current document. Thanks for help!